# html table column sizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple html table (one row to columns). I want one column to overflow with a scroll bar. The problem is that no matter what css setitngs I change the column size changes according to the text, and the scroll bar is horizontally and not vertically. 
What needs to be changed in order for my table to be the way I want?

Html code:

```
<table class="homepage_table">
    <tr >
        <td id="Articlesbar" width="20%"  >
            <%@include file="newsData.jsp" %>

        </td>


        <td id="about_td" width="80%"  >
    <div class="fadein">
    <img src="imp.gif">
  <img src="http://thefinancialbrand.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/tagline-tagcloud.gif">
  <img src="slogan1.gif">

</div>

        <div id="about_text" width="100%" height= "100px" >     
                Founded in 1992 as a Finance and Securities Company, 
                Imperia Bank converted into a fully fledged commercial bank in January 1996. 
                Since then the bank has had a long standing tradition of achieving strong financial performance and carrying out 
                expansion strategies while successfully focusing on efficient client service delivery.<br><br>
                Over the last 20 years, Imperia Bank has achieved a sustained growth in our customer deposit base which is largely attributed to the level of confidence our customers have in the bank and our corporate strategy.
                Currently we have 23 branches in our expanding branch network across major towns and cities.<br><br>
                Imperial Bank will continue to enhance the existing risk management parameters through the effective use of our newly installed and cutting edge core banking system.
                As part of our growth strategy, we are also continuing to recruit qualified professional staff, and providing appropriate training to our existing human resources to ensure we continue to meet evolving customer demands.
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and also (imported from a jsp page):

```
    <div id= "newsHeader"><%=header %></div>
    <div id = "newsBody"><%=newsBody %></div>
    <div id = "newsDate"><%=date %></div>

    <br>
```

CSS code:

```
.homepage_table
{
border: 250;
width: 100%;
height:500px;
margin:auto;
}
.homepage_table td
{
border:solid;

}
#about_td
{
background-image:url('http://www.promenadd.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/promenadd_grey_background.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 110%;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;

}
#about_text
{

    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color:steelblue;


}
#Articlesbar
{

 overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

#newsHeader
{
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
color:steelblue;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 20px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

#newsBody
{
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
color:red;
font-size: 14px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
#newsDate
{
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to using `table` as opposed to `DIV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was beaten to the punch but it looks like the poster wants the scrollbar on Articlesbar

So the simple method would be to set a height on that td, add a div inside it and add the scrollbar to that instead.

The structure would be like

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <div>
           </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

[here have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9gvD/)

Comment: I should have mentioned it , But in the "Articlesbar" I'm importing data from mysql. Will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

I put together this fiddle real quick:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GGn7y/)

And I added this CSS to your `#about_text` ID:

```
  max-height:200px;
  max-width:700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

I'm not certain if this is what you want, but I think it seems to do what you are looking for.

You can adjust the width/height as needed and the `overflow-y:scroll;` is what allows for the scroll bar to appear.